# Smart Contract count and release

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, storage

Using Ethereum Smart Contract i want to count incoming transaction from wallet A and after transactions count get to let's say 50 transactions release a single transaction to wallet B.

Let's say i've got 2 functions

```
    # Count transactions from the sender and attribute them to the receiver 
    countIncomingTransction(Sender,Receiver)

    # Will count the total transactions for each receiver and if
    # it hits n+50 transactions , then send one transaction to the receiver.
    releaseTransactionFromCount
```

Is it possible do to this with Smart Contracts?

Maybe there is other way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible do to this with Smart Contracts?

Yes, this would make one core functionality. You can find great information on how to make smart contracts here: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html

For developing/Interacting with them, I recommend the http://truffleframework.com/ !

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create just one public method and count incoming transactions and keep that number in a contract's storage variable. Then if it is 50 you can send transaction to the address you want. Just learn the basics of solidity language - the solution you need is pretty simple.